# php post data to django server-send largdata in multipl reqs or better way to escape postdata size restrictions and better way to accept data in parts

Tags: php, django

I have to send large post data from my php server to my django server . Since, the server restricts the postdata size (2MB, I think), we can modify it only by modifying some settings.  But, I dont want to do that. So, I am thinking of sending the data in multiple requests. For example, I want to send 10MB of data, then I will do 10/2 = 5 requests to send full data .

```
   Sample data : json_data = {'a':'aaa','b':'bbb' .... many like this}
```

I can simply get size first, then get total requests(10/2=5), divide the divide the data into 5 parts, then loop over 5 and send the data . But, how can I receive from the django server ? any good way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try compressing the data on the [php server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.examples.php) and then decompressing it with python on the [django server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html).

For example do something like this:

```
<?php
$string = 'Some information to compress';
$gz = gzopen('somefile.gz','w9');
gzwrite($gz, $string);
gzclose($gz);
?>
```

And

```
str_object1 = open('compressed_file', 'rb').read()
str_object2 = zlib.decompress(str_object1)
f.write(str_object2)
f.close()
```